# What does this SQLCMD statement do?

Tags: sqlcmd

I am new to SqlCmd. Can anyone give a short explanation of the following command?

```
SQLCMD -S VMLIVE-DATA\SQLSERVER -Q 
"RESTORE DATABASE GIS_ENG FROM DISK = N'\\10.143.251.101\ClientData\Backup\DatabaseBackups\DB_ENG.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1, 
MOVE N'DB_ENG' TO N'\\10.153.201.11\E$\SQLSERVER\Data\DB_ENG.mdf', 
MOVE N'DB_ENG_log' TO N'\\10.153.201.11\E$\SQLSERVER\Data\DB_ENG.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is saying to use SQLCMD.EXE connecting to the server instance VMLIVE-DATA\SQLSERVER, to run the script that will restore the GIS_ENG from a backup of the DB_ENG database, replacing the existing GIS_ENG if there is one.

The bulk of the text is the script -Q"RESTORE  ...  STATS=10".

The SQLCMD and RESTORE DATABASE parameters are define in the SQL Server documentation.

SQLCMD.EXE - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

RESTORE DATABASE - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

By default SQLCMD uses Trusted Connections (describe in the SQLCMD link) so it requires this to be run by a login with rights to restore a database.

Comment: What about this line "NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10"

Comment: NOUNLOAD means do not unload a tape. Commonly included in scripts, but hardly anybody uses tape anymore, so it is a NoOp. REPLACE forced the DB_ENG backup being restored to **replace** the existing GIS_ENG database as a new GIS_ENG database. STATS=10 defines what monitoring of the restore gets reported. In this case, every 10%. This is in the RESTORE link above or in linked topics connecting on BACKUP and RESTORE.